# Is there anything comparable to/resembling CNN's Fear and Greed Index?

Tags: investing

Are there trustworthy indicators, indices, metrics, or other modalities that entail the elements of behaviour, psychology, sentiments, and the like, behind finance and investing? I'm aware of only [CNN's Fear and Greed Index](http://money.cnn.com/data/fear-and-greed/)

Answer (score 1):

Lipper publishes data on the flow of funds in / out of stock and bond funds: http://www.lipperusfundflows.com

Robert Shiller works on stock market confidence indices that are published by Yale: http://som.yale.edu/faculty-research/our-centers-initiatives/international-center-finance/data/stock-market-confidence

Comment: +1. Thank you very much. I'll keep this question for a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to measure such things and they are generally called "sentiment indicators".  The ones that I have seen "work", in the sense that they show relatively high readings near market tops and relatively low readings near market bottoms.  The problem is that there are no thresholds that work consistently.  For example, at one market top a sentiment indicator may read 62.  At the next market top that same indicator might read 55.  So what threshold do you use next time?  Maybe the top will come at 53, or maybe it will not come until 65.

There was a time when I could have listed examples for you with the names of the indicators and what they signaled and when.  But I gave up on such things years ago after seeing such wide variation.  I have been at this a long time (30+ years), and I have not found anything that works as well as we would like at identifying a top in real time.  The best I have found (although it does give false signals) is a drop in price coupled with a bearish divergence in breadth.  The latter is described in "Stan Weinstein's Secrets For Profiting in Bull and Bear Markets".

Market bottoms are a little less difficult to identify in real time.  One thing I would suggest if you think that there is some way to get a significant edge in investing, is to look at the results of Mark Hulbert's monitoring of newsletters.  Virtually all of them rise and fall with the market and almost none are able to beat buy and hold of the Wilshire 5000 over the long term.